# Moment of inertia of a body

Tags: rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

I found the relation,$I=2\cdot T_\text{rot}$, where $I$ is the moment of inertia and $T_\text{rot}$ is the kinetic energy of rotation. Does moment of inertia depend on angular velocity? If it depends, how does it depend on velocity?

Comment: can you tell me how you found the relation?

Comment: From the book,PRADEEP`S FUNDAMENTAL OF PHYSICS.Moment of inertia=twice of kinetic energy of rotation@StephenWong

Comment: It should be $T=I\omega^2 /2$.

Comment: And can you tell me what page

Comment: page 5/54 @StephenWong

Comment: @Kyson Yeah, it's tight. But according $T=\frac{1}{2}I\omega^2$, we can't deduce the equation $I=2\cdot T_{rot}$.

Comment: the sentence i found has one condition,the body must have unit angular velocity about the given axis,can't it be generelizd?@StephenWong

Comment: I doubt you are wrong.  the unit of moment of inertia is different with energy. They aren't equal, and the equation of your question is wrong.

Comment: @nelsonningombam Of course not, it can't be generelized.

Comment: ok, then same body rotating about same axis  with different velocities will same moment of inertia?@StephenWong

Answer (score 0):

**Anwser: Moment of inertia doesn't depend on angular velocity.**

From the introductory textbooks, we know that $I=\sum m_is_i^2$, where $s_i$ is the distance $m_i$ to the axis of rotation. And in the situation of rotation around a fixed point, $I$ is a tensor, more complicated. Even so, the moment of inertia only depend on the positon of axis. In the situation of rotation around a fixed axis, $L=I\omega$, when $\omega$ changed, so angular momentum changed, but moment of inertia didn't change if the axis of rotation was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

For a rotating body, the kinetic energy is given by $$E=\frac12 I \omega^2\tag1$$

The angular momentum is $$L= I\omega\tag2$$

This means that the energy could be written as

$$E = \frac{L^2}{2I}\tag3$$

But the expression you wrote makes no sense.

As for your question, equation $(2)$ above shows that angular momentum depends on both angular velocity, and moment of intertia.